# Is a primitive matrix also aperiodic?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, markov-chains, spectral-graph-theory

In "Spectra of graphs" on p. 33, they state

> If $\Gamma$ is primitive (strongly connected, and such that not all
>   cycles have a length that is amultiple of some integer $d>1$), then...

Is the stated cycle condition the same as being aperiodic? If so, then why is it implied by primitivity? I know that irreducible and aperiodic imply primitive, but is the converse true as well?

For completeness, a matrix $M$ with nonegative entries is primitive if there exists a $k$ such that all entries of $M^k$ are positive.

Comment: The cycle condition is the same as aperiodicity, at least in the Markov chain context. Your term "primitive" to my understanding would be more commonly phrased as "ergodic".

Comment: I think so too. But in the Perron-Frobenius theorem and related literature, primitive seems to be used. In Markov chain language I believe my question would be: an ergodic chain will have the property that there is some time $t$ at which the chain can be in any state. If the later property holds for some chain, is the chain necessarily ergodic?